# Getting exception when read input box value using javascript executor in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium-webdriver

**Exception :**

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'unknown error: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of undefined

**Code :**

```
    string title = (string)js.ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].querySelector('#supplier-item-table_filter .form-control').value");
```

I am trying to get text from text box. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JS code is incorrect. The code refer to `argument[0]` which is the second parameter of `js.ExecuteScript("your-script...",the-argument);`. But you didn't pass the second parameter so it is error.

You can call `querySelector` from `document` object. See my code below.

```
string title = (string)js.ExecuteScript("return document.querySelector('#supplier-item-table_filter .form-control').value");
```